# PHP and Cloud Computing

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I have a php spider script that works for taking web site contents, and save the content to my database. It takes about 50 days to finish its job. I have a Virtual dedicated server for that, but as you realize, it takes huge time to finish execution. So, can cloud computing help my task? I searched on cloud computing and php, but I could not find nice guide for starting. Can you help me about how to start cloud computing for running php scripts faster?

Comment: PHP instructions are generally performed synchronously, unless you've written your spider using threads. Maybe an asynchronous approach would work better? [NodeJS](http://www.nodejs.org) is an excellent asynchronous language that works well with cloud computing. There are also many guides to get you started.

Comment: I upvoted you just to boost you up @ stackoverflow, but seriously if you want to avoid vote down you need to improve over question. Moreover, pelase edit and mention how many pages your current crawler crawls in 50 days plus detail configuration of your current machine.. .

Comment: Agree withh @PastorBones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for Amazon EC2. Some or should I say many big companies in the world goes for Amazon EC2.

But before upgrading to such high level I suggest you to rewrite your codes multi-threaded/mutli-core using Python or  C or Java, whichever seems to be your favorite.

For more information/startup guide/pricing for Amazon EC2 just check out this link:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/